# Lambda Expression compiling with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, extension-methods, func

I want to extend MVC with helpers. Let's assume I want to build an extension method that takes a property from the model and renders a paragraph.

I've written this code, but it won't compile. I didn't figure out how to do it:

```
public static class PExtension
{
    public static string PFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) where TModel: class 
    {
        var f = expression.Compile();
        // won't compile the line below:
        string propretyValue = f();
        return "<p>" + propretyValue + "</p>";
    }
}
```

For the record, my view should use something like:

```
@Html.PFor(m => m.Description);
```

Thanks.

### EDIT

Error Description: `*Delegate 'Func' does not take 0 arguments*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression parameter is specifying that the return value of the expression is TValue, but you are attempting to assign the return value of the compiled expression to a string. I'm guessing the compile error is something about "Cannot convert TValue to string"?

try this instead:

```
object propertyValue = f();
return string.Format( "<p>{0}</p>", propertyValue != null ? propertyValue.ToString() : string.Empty );
```

Update:

the error you posted indicates that you need to pass the model object to the expression in order for it to be evaluated. in looking at the [ASP.NET MVC source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/18cb600a3f7f60b621d7d04d024b440fd6f185b3#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/TemplateHelpers.cs) for how they do their extensions methods, they are obtaining the model from the ViewData like this:

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
```

so try this:

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
object propertyValue = f((TModel)metadata.Model);
return string.Format( "<p>{0}</p>", propertyValue != null ? propertyValue.ToString() : string.Empty );
```

Comment: Excellent, I will post an answer with a little correction, but you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, code looks like this:

```
 public static class PExtension
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) where TModel : class
        {
            ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", metadata.Model != null ? metadata.Model.ToString() : string.Empty));
        }
    }
```